# SQL - Filter data where number of lines is variable

Tags: sql

I have invoice data (sample below) where each invoice has one or more lines and each line has one or more sequential assigned reviewers.

I want to filter the data to return only invoices where all lines have been approved by all reviewers.

So in the sample below I want 123 to return, but not 234 because invoice line 2 is still pending for reviewer 2.  I am fairly new to SQL and at a loss on how to do this.

| InvoiceNo. | InvoiceLine | ApprovalSeq | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 1 | Approved |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | Approved |
| 123 | 2 | 1 | Approved |
| 234 | 1 | 1 | Approved |
| 234 | 1 | 2 | Approved |
| 234 | 2 | 1 | Approved |
| 234 | 2 | 2 | Pending |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method for this is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select invoiceno
from t
group by invoiceno
having count(*) = sum(case when status = 'Approved' then 1 else 0 end);
```

Actually, because `'Approved'` may be the minimum status alphabetically, you can use:

```
select invoiceno
from t
group by invoiceno
having max(status) = 'Approved'
```

Comment: The first solution here works really well to return the fully approved invoice numbers. What I ultimately need to do is create a report that shows the line item details of the returned invoices where all lines are approved. When I use this query and add in the additional lines, I get all approved lines (it leaves out not approved lines) and not just approved invoices. What additional details do I need to add?

Comment: @hjReads . . . This question explicitly says that you want to find invoices.  If you want the details, you can use `in`, `join`, `exists`, or window functions.

Answer (score 2):

you can use case statement to have conditional count.

```
select invoiceno
from invoice
group by invoiceno
having count(*) = count(case when status = 'Approved' then 1 else null end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using sub-query as one of the options:

```
SELECT DISTINCT InvoiceNo FROM TABLE x LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT InvoiceNo FROM TABLE x1 WHERE Status != 'Approved') notAppr
ON x.InvoiceNo = notAppr.InvoiceNo
WHERE notAppr.InvoiceNo IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been shown how to get the invoice numbers where no approval is pending by aggreating your invoice line approval table. You probably want to use this to select from the invoice table:

```
select *
from invoice
where invoiceno in
        (select invoiceno from invoice_line_approval group by invoiceno having ...)
```

If so, you don't have to aggregate the whole invoice line approval table, but merely check whether a non-approved row exists for an invoice with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from invoice i
where not exists
(
  select null
  from invoice_line_approval ila
  where ila.invoiceno = i.invoiceno
  and ila.status <> 'Approved'
);
```

(If the status can be null, then you need `and (ila.status <> 'Approved' or ila.status is null)`, though.)